# Container live migration

Tags: python, linux, docker

I want to move running container from host to host with Docker.
I am using `docker checkpoint create` command, and the thing is that it creates checkpoints as root, and I cannot touch them in Python. Is there anyway either force docker to create files as another user, or scp root-made files within Python?

Comment: why not run python with sudo?

Comment: The code is part web server, I don't think it's good to run it with sudo in production.

Comment: The code that does the live migration of your containers is part of your webserver? You should probably split those out.

Answer (score 0):

When a colleague and I gave a [live migration talk and demo](https://www.slideshare.net/PhilEstes/live-container-migration-openstack-summit-barcelona-2016) at OpenStack Summit Barcelona, we only used `sudo` on the tar command to extract the created checkpoint into a file in `/tmp`, which is then used to ssh/scp to another host. This isn't the perfect answer as of course you still need root permissions to access the created checkpoint within Docker's metadata directory, but shows that you could at least extract that one root-requiring action to a separate privileged script, with the rest of the migration requiring only "normal" access to docker client commands.

You can see our migration script example here:
https://github.com/stmuraka/container-migration/blob/master/Examples/migrateExample.sh

Comment: Hi Phil, I've watched the demo before :) but I've found that python-api fits more for my problem, because the server is in Django, so I've wrapped experimental features on python and because of  "move" is automated action, which used for server re-re-balancing-like feature,I can't do it with `sudo` . But it was turned out that only problematic files are oinly dump.log and restore.log which didn't have read access, hence obviously it's not mandatory for `container start`, I'm skipping that files.
Thanks!